# Generic extend can't add the same type

Tags: java

I'm new to these generic types. In the below code, I created a method that accepts a List of items that extends "String".

My Question? - When the list can be assigned with a new list that is , why can't a string "test" can be added...It gives me a compilation error.

```
public class Child {
    public void takeList(List<? extends String> list){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not the runtime type that's relevant here. `list` is still of type `List<? extends String>`, you've just happened to assign it to a `new ArrayList<String>()`. Consider this:

```
list = rand() ? new ArrayList<String>() : new ArrayList<NotString>();
```

The compiler could not possibly tell if `list.add("test")` will be valid -- it only makes decisions based on the compile-time type of `list`.

Note that in reality nothing extends `String`, it's a `final` class.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference.  It takes a list that contains one type of thing (a thing that extends string).  This list may be a subclass of String and therefore not be a String iyswim.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html Upper bounded wildcards.

If it was

```
     public void takeList(List<? *super* String> list){
```

Then you could add strings to it, because the list is guaranteed to be able to accept Strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a variable with a wildcard, and a method that takes the generic type parameter, Java cannot ensure type safety.  It must disallow this call.

Consider a `List<? extends Animal>` for example.  You may have assigned it `List<Dog>`, but the variable could be assigned a `List<Squid>`.  You shouldn't be allowed to add a `Dog` to such a list.

To allow the `add` method to be called, remove the wildcard.

```
public void takeList(List<String> list){
```

Besides, [`String` is `final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), so there really is no point to saying `? extends String`.